AS400 PGM used keyword FIXNBR *ZONED / *INPUTPACKED
In AS400 I need to see if a program was compiled with the keyword FIXNBR with a value other than *NONE (so *ZONED or *INPUTPACKED).
I already tried using the DSPPGM, DPSPGMREF and DSPOBJD commands, but I couldn't locate that attribute.

According to IBM's Barbara Morris, who is a developer for the RPG IV compiler,

There is nothing visible in the module or program object to indicate
that FIXNBR(*ZONED) was used for the compile. The FIXNBR parameter
value just affects how the compiler generates the program; it doesn't
become an attribute of the compiled object.


I think this is correct. It would be nice if the exact command(s) used to build an object were stored with the object (maybe an idea for the future?), but we have what we have. If you're lucky enough to still have the compile listing, it is in there. Short of that, I think the only way to know would be to construct some data which would cause the program to fail or not, depending on the value of FIXNBR, and run the program on that data.
